# How do I copy all files that end with .txt from cookbook to node on chef?

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I have a chef cookbook that has a bunch of files that end in ".txt" in my /files/default folder.
How can I add to my chef recipe a way to move all files that end in ".txt" from my files directory to a specific directory on my node?

Here is what  I have:

```
remote_directory "/opt/info"  do
 source [/*.txt/]
 owner 'root'
 group 'root'
 mode '0640'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `source` property of `remote_directory` resource takes a directory name in `files/default` of the cookbook, and not files.

So you should move your `*.txt` files to `files/default/info`. Example contents:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
file6.txt
```

Then in your recipe specify the `info` directory in which `*.txt` files are present:

```rb
remote_directory '/opt/info' do
  source 'info'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0640'
end
```

This will copy all files from `files/default/info` of your cookbook to `/opt/info` on the node.

Comment: if you have many files, consider storing them in a accessible location to your node, and download them.